# 2010: Search keywordquery: Can't find Web GUID in result

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, enterprise-search

A keyword search request with "ContentClass:STS_Web" gets all the webs the current user has access to. I need the SPWeb-GUID from every search result, but I haven't found a way yet. The standard result has no ID column. Adding properties to the Query like "ID", "GUID", "Web-Id" resulted in an always empty column or the search executed forever without results (i waited 3 minutes or so).

How do I get the GUID?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution: the property is "WebId" and the result GUIDs look like this:

{0a953ee9-b508-4184-91a7-0aa02653b262}